# Defining an API with swagger: GET call that uses JSON in parameters

Tags: rest, swagger-2.0

I am trying to create a proper, REST API, and document it with Swagger (2.0).

So, I have an API call that is a query, ie, it makes no changes and doesn't create anything (idempotent and safe). But it requires passing in a complex JSON parameter (list of items, 2 or 3 sets of addresses, etc). So I'm doing a GET with a parameter thats URL encoded JSON. That seems like the proper way to do it.

I see so often API's like this where they do it as a POST for this reason, but that's an incorrect use of the POST verb.

I'm seeing lots of swagger API's that do this...

I can't figure out if there's a way to do a proper rest API with Swagger, using a JSON parameter. You can define the parameter as a string, of course, and pass your encoded JSON into it, but then the swagger tooling doesn't understand that there's a schema/definition for it.

Is swagger not able to properly document this kind of call?

Answer (score 9):

#### OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0)

OpenAPI 2.0 does not support objects in query strings, it only supports primitive values and arrays of primitives. The most you can do is define your parameter as `type: string`, add an `example` of a JSON value, and use `description` to document the JSON object structure.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: params
          required: true
          description: A JSON object with the `id` and `name` properties
          type: string
          example: '{"id":4,"name":"foo"}'
```

#### OpenAPI 3.x

JSON in query string can be described using OpenAPI 3.x. In OAS 3, query parameters can be primitives, arrays as well as objects, and you can specify how these parameters should be serialized – flattened into `key=value` pairs, encoded as a JSON string, and so on.

For query parameters that contain a JSON string, use the `content` keyword to define a `schema` for the JSON data:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
...

paths:
  /something:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: params
          required: true

          # Parameter is an object that should be serialized as JSON
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  id:
                    type: integer
                  name:
                    type: string
```

This corresponds to the following GET request (before URL encoding):

```
GET /something?params={"id":4,"name":"foo"}
```

or after URL encoding:

```
GET /something?params=%7B%22id%3A4%2C%22name%22%3A%22foo%22%7D
```

**Note for Swagger UI users:**
Parameters with `content` are supported in **Swagger UI 3.23.8+** and **Swagger Editor 3.6.34+**.

**Workaround for earlier versions of UI/Editor:**
Define the parameter as just `type: string` and add an `example` of the JSON data. You lose the ability to describe the JSON schema for the query string, but "try it out" will work.

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: params
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string                    # <-------
          example: '{"id":4,"name":"foo"}'  # <-------
```

Answer (score 1):

For .Net and Swashbuckle (tested on 3.0)
I have a generic class JsonModelBinder that implements IModelBinder interface. The class  is used like this:

```
public IActionResult SomeAction(
        [FromRoute] int id, 
        [FromQuery][ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(JsonModelBinder<SomeModel>))] SomeModelquery query) => {}
```

I have created Operation filter that does the following:

- Removes parameters created by Swashbuckle from properties of my model
- Add query parameter of type string

As a result in Swagger I have a text field where I can insert json and test requests

```
public class JsonModelBinderOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null || context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod != HttpMethod.Get.ToString())
            return;
        //Find json parameters
        var jsonGetParameters = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Cast<ControllerParameterDescriptor>()
            .Where(p => p.ParameterInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(c => c.AttributeType == typeof(ModelBinderAttribute) && c.NamedArguments.Any(IsJsonModelBinderType))).ToArray();

        if (jsonGetParameters.Length > 0)
        {
            //Select parameters names created by Swagger from json parameters
            var removeParamNames = new HashSet<string>(context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Where(d => jsonGetParameters.Any(p => p.Name == d.ParameterDescriptor.Name)).Select(p => p.Name));
            //Create new Swagger parameters from json parameters
            var newParams = jsonGetParameters.Select(p => new NonBodyParameter()
            {
                In = "query",
                Name = p.Name,
                Type = "string",
                Description = "Json representation of " + p.ParameterType.Name
            });
            //Remove wrong parameters and add new parameters
            operation.Parameters = operation.Parameters.Where(p => p.In != "query" || !removeParamNames.Contains(p.Name)).Concat(newParams).ToList();
        }
    }

    private static bool IsJsonModelBinderType(CustomAttributeNamedArgument arg)
    {
        var t = arg.TypedValue.Value as Type;
        return t != null && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(JsonModelBinder<>));
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I use IsAssignableFrom because I have classes derived from JsonModelBinder. You can omit it if you don't inherit
- You can also omit GetGenericTypeDefinition if your binder is not generic
- This solution doesn't check for parameter name collision, though you should never have it if the API made with common sense

Comment: Hai, Where you get `NonBodyParameter` Instance? It's an instance to handle our data based on our need? and how about `JsonModelBinder<>`?

Comment: @FadhlyPermata, it's Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.NonBodyParameter, a class that describes parametrs for Swagger

Comment: JsonModelBinder is only used to determine which API use it