# How to change query parameter name in swagger?

Tags: rest, get, swagger, openapi

I am trying to get this url:

`https://search.me/Search/api/search?map=%7B%22query%22:%22CSCI+250%22,%22rows%22:500,%22term%22:%222181%22,%22career%22:%22%22,%7D`

without converting special characters to HEX to URL would be:

`https://search.me/Search/api/search?map={query:CSCI-250,rows:500,term:2181,career:}`

I know it is not possible to serialize special characters as hex in openapi 3.0.0, so I am fine with the full JSON in the query parameter.

Where the parameter is a JSON -> URI
The JSON is:

```
{
  map:  {
    "query": "CSCI 250",
    "rows": 500,
    "term": 2181,
    "career": ""
  }
}
```

but swagger instead renders:

`https://search.me/search/api/search?query=CSCI-250&rows=500&term=2181&career=`

As you can see, special characters are then converted into HEX.

Below is my path. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
paths:
  /search:
    get:
      summary: Search
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: map
        description: JSON for lookup
        required: true
        schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/QueryParams'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Course search response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/QueryResults'
        400:
          description: Bad request
```

Comment: Is the expected example `.../map?=CSCI-250` correct? It has `=` directly after `?` so the first parameter name seems to be missing.

Comment: I added the correct URL that I need. @Helen

Comment: I don't mind not converting to hex as I documented this, I just want the correct parameter name to be displayed. Should be `map` not `query`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining an API with swagger: GET call that uses JSON in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820064/defining-an-api-with-swagger-get-call-that-uses-json-in-parameters)

Comment: ^^ Please see the linked question for the syntax used to describe JSON in query strings. Your parameter `name` is correct, but you need to wrap the `schema` into `content`+`application/json`. Also note that Swagger UI currently [does not support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4442) such parameters.

Comment: @Helen that is for swagger 2.0. I am using openapi 3.0.0

Comment: [My answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223964/113116) is for OpenAPI 3.0.