# Describing a json parameter in Swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi

**Issue**

According to [this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters) and [this](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#parameter-object-examples) Swagger supports complex parameters, but when I try to describe a json parameter Swagger Editor shows the following issue:

> Could not render ParameterRow, see the console.

**Expected behavior**

Json object as a parameter.

**YAML**

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Trackmeeasy API
paths:
  /getLabelUrl.action:
    post:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  type:
                    type: string
                  color:
                    type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

**To reproduce...**

1. Copy yaml
2. Go to http://editor.swagger.io
3. Paste yaml
4. See error

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the latest versions of Swagger UI and Swagger Editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenAPI 3.0 parameters with `content` are supported in **Swagger UI 3.23.8+** and **Swagger Editor 3.6.34+**.

If you use an earlier version of UI or Editor, you can use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223964/113116) to get "try it out" support - i.e. define the parameter as just `type: string` and add an `example` of the JSON data. You lose the ability to describe the JSON schema for the query string, but "try it out" will work.

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          schema:
            type: string                           # <-------
          example: '{"type":"foo","color":"bar"}'  # <-------
```

**Note: If you are designing a new API** rather than describing an existing API, you should post complex data, such as JSON objects, in the request body instead:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /getLabelUrl.action:
    post:
      requestBody:    # <-----
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              ...
```

Or if using a query parameter is more appropriate, consider "flattening" the object into key=value pairs, e.g.:

```
POST /getLabelUrl.action?type=foo&color=bar
```

This serialization strategy is defined using `style: form` and `explode: true`. See [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query) for more example of query parameter serialization.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /getLabelUrl.action:
    post:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              type:
                type: string
              color:
                type: string

          # style=form + explode=true is the default serialization strategy
          # so you can omit this
          style: form
          explode: true
```